# How to reconcile and add files to new changelist?

Tags: perforce

Perforce has a command `p4 reconcile`. It adds files to the 'default changelist', or if I use the `-c` flag, the particular changelist whose number I give. How can I run the reconcile command but add the files to a *new* changelist?

Answer (score 1):

First, create the new changelist:

```
p4 change -o | sed 's/<enter.*>/My Changelist/' | p4 change -i
Change 5 created.
```

(Depending on your operating system, you may have to do something slightly different to provide a changelist description for your changelist; I used the Unix 'sed' utility in this case.)

Then, specify that changelist to reconcile:

```
p4 reconcile -c 5
```

Alternatively, you could let reconcile add the files to the default changelist, then subsequently use 'p4 reopen' to move the files to the changelist you prefer, after you have created it and received its changelist number:

```
p4 reopen -c 5 //...
```